# Image container width does not change on resize in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design

Again I have a problem with Firefox.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjecdw2t/13/) to illustrate the problem. When you resize the window vertically you can see that the width of the container doesn't change (blue background). Is there a way to tell the `.slideshow-elem` container to adjust it's width depending on the image inside of it for Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change width of image container on change of browsers' height?

Comment: Well, I just wanted the images to be responsive but I need them also to be in a container because some of them will need to be vertically centered. Now I have this container which should be kind of invisible, it's width should be that of the image inside of it. Is that possible? In Safari and Chrome it looks just as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what you wanted, but I'll try to help. I looked at the jsfiddle on Chrome to see what you wanted , since you said it worked there. The problem seemed HTML related.  The CSS was fine. I reformatted your HTML to look cleaner.

```
<body>

<div class = "slideshow">
<div class = "gallery">

<img src = "http://i.imgur.com/ti943oY.jpg" class = "slideshow-elem" width="400" height="600" />
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/ti943oY.jpg" class = "slideshow-elem" width="400" height="600" />

</div>
</div> 

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjecdw2t/31/

Like this ?

**UPDATE:** 
I noticed you didn't end your `<img>` tags with the `/>`. If you look in the JSFiddle you posted, there are some divs highlighted red which means there was a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I said I need the images to be in a container because some of them will need to be vertically centered. I'll update the Fiddle with an example of what I mean.